# Twilio Chat getChannelDescriptors() paginator page items undefined

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Recently ran into an anomaly that we couldn't figure out to the end but had to program in a failsafe.

The problem is that the [Paginator](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/4.0.0/docs/Paginator.html) returned by the [Client.getUserChannelDescriptors()](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/4.0.0/docs/Client.html#getUserChannelDescriptors__anchor) has next pages, but `page.items` returns `undefined` and the following while loop will remain in infinitive loop:

```
async getAllRoomDescriptors() {
    try {

        var descPaginator = await TwilioClient.getChannelDescriptors()
        var descs = descPaginator.items.concat([])
        
        console.log('descPaginator: ', descPaginator); // Paginator looks normal

        // NB! This is infinitive loop!
        while (descPaginator.hasNextPage) {
            var pag = descPaginator.nextPage()     // returns another Paginator (page)
            console.log('pag.items: ', pag.items); // returns undefined!!!
            descs = descs.concat(pag.items)
        }
        return descs
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error)
    }
}
```

In order to solve this *infinitive loop* **and** *undefined page items* I added the following failsafes (read hacks) to get it working without understanding the root cause of the issue.

```
async getAllRoomDescriptors() {
    try {
        var descPaginator = await TwilioClient.getChannelDescriptors()
        var descs = descPaginator.items.concat([])
        var currPage = 0
        var maxAllowedPages = 60

        while (descPaginator.hasNextPage) {
            currPage++
            var pag = descPaginator.nextPage()

            // 1st sign of trouble if items are undefined
            if(!pag.items) break;

            descs = descs.concat(pag.items)

            // 2nd problem, infintity loop avoidance check
            if(currPage >= maxAllowedPages) break;
        }
        return descs
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error)
    }
}
```

All [Changelogs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/javascript/changelog) from 3.3.5 up to 4.0.0 don't mention anything about it and the documentation on how the [Paginator](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/4.0.0/docs/Paginator.html) work hasn't changed either.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue. Same behavior on both 3.3.5 and 4.0.0.
Also this seems to be isolated to specific user as I couldn't recreate this in another used which much less channels. This happened to the most "loaded" Twilio user.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code: `descPaginator.nextPage()` returns a **Promise** so you have to use `await` again. Something like this:

```
while (descPaginator.hasNextPage) {
  descPaginator = await descPaginator.nextPage();
  //do stuff
}
```